# Vulnerable OS's?

Tags: penetration-test, professional-education, exploit, known-vulnerabilities, operating-systems

Which vulnerable OS's like for example [DVL](http://www.damnvulnerablelinux.org/) would you recommend for someone to use for the purpose of pentest/exploitation learning?

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it a bit ironic that we're not using DVL (Damn **Vulnerable** Linux)  because is not _maintained_ anymore?

Comment: Also see here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35756/where-can-i-find-a-vulnerable-operating-system-to-practice-pentests-on/35767#35767

Comment: I think, Windows 95/98 are very vulnerable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a couple of good ones in addition to DVL, that I've come across

- [Metasploitable](http://www.metasploit.com/express/community) is designed for testing out some of Metasploits functionality. There's some good information on using it in the free [Metasploit Unleashed](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Metasploitable) course.
- There's also [DVWA](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/) from a web applications perspective

**EDIT:**

Another good list I came across on a blog recently, has quite a few potential vulnerable apps

- [Pentest lab vulnerable servers-applications list](http://r00tsec.blogspot.com/2011/02/pentest-lab-vulnerable-servers.html)

Answer (score 36):

There is quite a lot of them:

- [Metasploitable](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Metasploitable): Currently there are 2 versions.
- [Kioptrix](http://www.kioptrix.com/blog/?page_id=135): Currently 4 challenges.
- [Hackademic](http://ghostinthelab.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/hackademic-rtb1-root-this-box/): Apparently 2 VM, check [1](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Hackademic-RTB1) and [2](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Hackademic-RTB2).
- [pWnOS](http://pwnos.com/): Currently 2 challenges.

Standalone which you can install directly without VM, this is to hone your Webattack-Fu:

- [OWASP WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project)
- [Damn Vulnerable Web Application](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)
- [Mutillidae](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=mutillidae/mutillidae-deliberately-vulnerable-php-owasp-top-10)

Comment: In addition, Windows Server 2003 with no patches would be a good start.

Comment: @ponsfonze Yeah indeed, but since the OP has tagged his question `linux` I didn't add it.

Answer (score 21):

I'd suggest in additiona to HamZa DzCyberDeV's answer:

[Pentester Labs](https://www.pentesterlab.com/exercises) exercises which are full VMs as well as full detailed walkthroughs etc. These are great for all skill levels and i've found them most useful.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Thank Louis Nyffenegger https://twitter.com/snyff he's the guy who's been kind enough to make it happen :)

Answer (score 8):

Another good one is http://exploit-exercises.com/:

> exploit-exercises.com provides a variety of virtual machines,
>   documentation and challenges that can be used to learn about a variety
>   of computer security issues such as privilege escalation,
>   vulnerability analysis, exploit development, debugging, reverse
>   engineering, and general cyber security issues.

Answer (score 7):

Did a little research on my own and found the following:

- [De-ICE PenTest LiveCDs Project](http://heorot.net/livecds/)
- [Web Security Dojo](http://www.mavensecurity.com/web_security_dojo/) - one more web appsec training environment (based on ubuntu)
- [Holynix](http://pynstrom.net/holynix.php)

Answer (score 5):

I know of [LAMP security training](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lampsecurity/files/) and [PwnOS](http://www.neildickson.com/os/)

Answer (score 3):

To a greater or lesser degree, almost all OS'es should be counted as vulnerable out of the box, so in my opinion you should practice on Win XP, 2000 and possibly Win 7, Linux (of any type), MAC OS X etc. Once you understand the vulnerabilities, then patch and apply secure hardening guidance and retest the same platforms. You will then get some valuable experience as to how OS'es can be secured.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Question: servers-for-penetration-testing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/servers-for-penetration-testing/1739#1739). It has many Operating Systems and live servers that you are allowed to attack, hack and learn...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a little money to spend then you can grab an MSDN OS license to gain access to the various Windows OS versions.  If you answer the questions correctly, you can get an MSDN license for $100 via BizSpark:  http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/Faqs.aspx

**UPDATE:**  Check out this list:  http://www.felipemartins.info/2011/05/pentesting-vulnerable-study-frameworks-complete-list/

Comment: Are you implying that Windows is a "vulnerable OS" and useful only for "exploitation learning"?

Comment: Btw, BizSpark rocks, but its not just a question of "answering the questions correctly". (See there "Who is eligible for BizSpark?").

Comment: No.  I never said or implied Windows is only useful for "exploitation learning".  Windows is a great gaming platform! And wouldn't you agree most (all?) default Windows installations is the equivalent to running a vulnerable OS?

Comment: when you say default are you refering to a patched or unpatched system connected to the network/web?

Answer (score 1):

Hi just on the following of "*vulnerable*" VM's I have a great resource for you guys just thought id pop it on here. It's called [VulnHub](http://www.vulnhub.com).

Comment: A bit more detail would be nice but it seems like a good resource...

Answer (score 1):

OWASP site, specifically

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Vulnerable_Web_Applications_Directory_Project#tab=Virtual_Machines_or_ISOs

Contains links to Virtual machines etc, some maintained others not