# Designing a Capture The Flag target and game management system

Tags: penetration-test, ctf

I've attended several CTF contests and I'd like to implement a CTF system for my students. I asked Google about designing such system but it's fruitless. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you refering to Capture the Flag? I assume you mean in relation to social engineering. What do you teach and at what level (elementry, intermediate, high school, university)?

Comment: Oh, I'm teaching cyber security at a university. I want to build a CTF system for students to practice simple hacking techniques.

Comment: Do you want a computer system with intentional flaws to allow students to discover and exploit vulnerabilites?

Comment: Yep, that's the system I want. :(

Comment: Did you see this question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1735

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servers for penetration testing](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1735/servers-for-penetration-testing)

Comment: The term CTF is kinda ambigous. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/what-hacking-competitions-challenges-exist/3648#3648

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned by this.josh, you can look at multiple already existing vulnerable applications in this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1735) or you might try to find existing CTF source codes - for example, look at the [OWASP hackademic challenges](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-hackademic-challenges/). You might just take one of these and modify them slightly for your students. Also, try to contact authors of past CTF's - they might help you by giving their source codes. Here's a handy [calendar of various CTF challenges](http://capture.thefl.ag/calendar/) with appropriate links.

Answer (score 8):

I once stumbled upon a OS VM machine which is called Metasploitable, it is made by the creators of Metasploit and is used as a target machine for practicing.

It is, and this is a quote from the page:

> Ubuntu 8.04 server install on a VMWare 6.5 image. A number of vulnerable packages are >included, including an install of tomcat 5.5 (with weak credentials), distcc, tikiwiki, >twiki, and an older mysql.

If you go through some exploits yourself, you can assign these tasks to your students and give them some guidelines.

Here is the link:

[Metasploitable](http://blog.metasploit.com/2010/05/introducing-metasploitable.html)

And a link for the metasploit framework

[Metasploit](http://metasploit.com/)

And last but not least, Backtrack 5, if you havnt already introduced your students to this OS and compilation of pentest software:

[Backtrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of creating a new demo system with intentional vulnerabilities from scratch, take a look first at the existing ones:

Google's Gruyere codelab, "Web Application Exploits and Defenses" http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/

OWASP's WebGoat: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project

Answer (score 5):

organizer of previous CTF events here.

First thing, write down a simple score board system, then decide how many and which categories you would like to have on ur event. If you look at this photo https://p.twimg.com/Ad_ncp0CAAE7L_I.jpg:large < its the last CTF I organized at codebits.eu it was an event for 10 teams with 4 elements each.

It had 4 categories:

- Web apps
- Forensics
- Pwnables
- Trivia

If you want to have a look at some sample CTF challenges I have a list of websites I can provide you with:

-http://balgan.eu/?page_id=67 << (My Website)

-http://hackerschool.org/DefconCTF/17/B300.html

-http://nopsr.us/

-http://leetmore.ctf.su/hack-lu-2010/

-http://www.routards.org/2010/06/defcon-17-quals-forensics-300.html

-http://www.vnsecurity.net/2010/05/defcon-18-quals-writeups-collection/

-http://www.vnsecurity.net/c/capture-the-flag/

Hope its helpeful, feel free to ask more question if u need some help!

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [the International Capture The Flag](http://ictf.cs.ucsb.edu/) run by folks at UCSB.

Answer (score 1):

If case anyone still needs an ingame management system for CTF's my research team wrote our own scoreboard which we have now made available to the world at: http://www.ptcoresec.eu/?p=347