# Are there specific sub-fields of Hacking?

Tags: network, malware, operating-systems

For example, network hacking, operating system hacking, website hacking, malware deployment.

Pardon my inexperience, but these seem like they require very specific skill-sets and labelling them all as 'Hacking' feels too broad.

Are there standard subfields of computer hacking? (I don't mean the white/grey/black hat types of hackers themselves). If so, what are the details of each?

Comment: If you replace "hacking" with "security" it becomes apparent that every "sub-field" of technology has a security aspect to it. For any technology there are people who "hack" it.

Comment: This questions is way too broad and subject to debate. But here, check out this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8478/70301) and this [/r/netsec wiki post](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/wiki/start)

Comment: I think you have an incorrect understanding of what 'hacking' means. Any system that exists can be 'hacked', so every system becomes a 'sub-field'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most security Capture the Flag competitions ('hacking competitions' if you will), assign challenges a few different categories:

- Forensics
- Exploitation
- Reverse engineering
- Network
- Cryptography
- Misc / Programming

If you're looking for a broad overview I'd recommend reading [Hacking: The Art of Exploitation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593271441) which covers each of the above and provides practical exercises.