# Where can I find a vulnerable operating system to practice pentests on?

Tags: linux, penetration-test, known-vulnerabilities

I am looking for vulnerable operating systems that are used for practicing pentests. Damn Vulnerable Linux (DVL) is not maintained anymore. Are there any other simillar OS´s to download somewhere that are runnable on VirtualBox?

When I google for such operating systems, all I get are links to articles on DVL, but there should be a lot of DVL-like OS´s out there I think.