# Deliberate Vulnerable Openstack images for penetration testing/training or research

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, research, openstack

I was just wondering if there are already deliberate vulnerable Openstack images for penetration testing/training or research. Something in line with OWASP's DVWA e.t.c....there quite a lot out there for web applications especially.  I am doing a research and will be very glad if someone already has something like that or possibly direct me to the right place. The similar projects as mentioned [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183/vulnerable-oss) differ from what I am seeking for. While most of the existing solutions focus on linux distributions and web applications,  [OpenStack](http://www.openstack.org/) composes of several cloud services which could have several types of vulnerabilities. Moreover, OpenStack could be installed standalone via [ironic](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Ironic).  Many thanks !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vulnerable OS's?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/183/vulnerable-oss)

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of [Vulnerable OS's?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/183/61443) because that one is specifically about the OS, and this is specifically about the application stack.

Comment: @Mike, I agree with you. Openstack is a large stack composed of several services. Installing openstack on a vulnerable Linux OS e.g. from one of the lists doesn't solve the problem. A possible approach is an openstack installation on which all the security updates/patches have been stripped of...It's about having openstack specific vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching across the internet, it seems there are really no "ready made" vulnerable OpenStack images similar to web applications like OWASP DVWA. However, I think a starting point is to install old OpenStack releases  and also install some vulnerable software on it. I have found icehouse easy install [here](https://github.com/StackGeek/openstackgeek). I will like to start working on this...any one interested in this topic is welcome.